# Android WVGA800 and 854

Tags: android

Although my relativelayout looks very similar on WVGA800 and WVGA854 on the emulator, theres different spacing on some of the objects because I'm going off of marginleft or marginright. Since the 854 is a greater width, its pushing some objects differently. Is there any way I could target either one to adjust for the different margins?

Answer (score 2):

Use `-long` as a [resource set qualifier](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/resources-i18n.html#AlternateResources) to identify "long" screens like WVGA854.